# How do I show the error string between typography tag

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show the error string in between my typography tag if there is an error.Problem is when i log that error into the console it is shown there but when I use that same variable in between typography tag it does not show any value.

For starters I tried to declare a variable in the render method.Then I called the handle_image_error from the onChange of the input type.

```
handle_image_error = e => {


    if (1) {
      return "Size must be lower than 3MB";
    }
  };
  render() {
    let image_error = 0;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          accept="image/*"
          type="file"
          id="image_upload"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          onChange={e => {
            image_error = this.handle_image_error(e);
            console.log("image_error", image_error);
          }}
        />

        <label htmlFor="image_upload">
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span">
            Upload Photo
          </Button>
        </label>
        <Typography>{image_error}</Typography>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I want to show the error returned by handle_image_error function to be show in typography tag. I have changed the condition of function to be always true for debugging purpose. Here is the link for sandbox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-shape-58ilo
or it can be this I am not sure how to share the sandbox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-shape-58ilo?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     image_error: 0,
    }
  }
  handle_image_error = e => {
    if (1) {
      return "Size must be lower than 3MB";
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          accept="image/*"
          type="file"
          id="image_upload"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          onChange={e => {
            this.setState({image_error: this.handle_image_error(e)});
            console.log("image_error", this.state.image_error);
          }}
        />

        <label htmlFor="image_upload">
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span">
            Upload Photo
          </Button>
        </label>
        <Typography>{this.state.image_error}</Typography>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Your variable `image_error` is just a local variable with initial value `0`, so React renders `0`. Now you change the value of `image_error` when an image is uploaded, but React doesn't knows that the value of `image_error` has been changed and hence the component is not re-rendered.
React doesn't tracks changes of local variables. If you wish a re-render, either use `props` or `state` as React watches for changes in them only and re-renders when they change.
Hence you need to use state, initialise the state in `constructor`. Now when you need to update the state, use the method `this.setState` and React will know when state updates. Don't assign directly to state.

Comment: I am trying to do this without using state. Can't it be done using a normal variable preferably in render method?

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt I think you're misunderstanding how React works. React doesn't update based on changed instance variables, only props and state.

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt see edited answer. If you don't like `this.state`, switch to function component and use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), but that's basically same as state but in function component.